# grep -v [string] for whole folder

Tags: text-processing, grep, filenames

I have a folder, `/path/` , with files all formatted to `.filetype`,  and I am looking to perform:

`grep -v [string] [filename] > [filename copy].filetype`

for ALL items in this folder. I assume I'll have to do `cd /path.` and set up a loop. I am really not familiar with the syntax, and I don't want to mess anything up, would it be formatted something like:

```
for [something] in *.filetype
do
  grep -v [string] [filename] > "[filename].filetype"
done
```

??

if it helps, my files are NOT formatted** a specific way (e.g. by time or date) so order does not matter, but I very much need the name of the file to be conserved. not sure if that's possible

thank in advance, sorry if I gave you a headache.

edits: **

> I meant to say that I don't have a particular organization of my files.

Comment: You need to add some identifier for your new files or use a new directory. Otherwise, you're going to overwrite your old files. For example, assume you have another directory `new`, and then run something like this: `for i in *.<filetype>; do grep -v '<token>' "$i" > "new/$i"; done`. Remember, if you're not sure about what should be the output of your script/command, create a copy of your files first.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "with files all formatted to `.filetype`".  You later also say "my files are NOT formatted a specific way". Could you describe with words what you want to do to each file? Possibly something like "remove all lines matching (some specific pattern) and save the result in a new file". Your placeholders are confusing since you use `[something]` in the loop header, but then don't mention `[something]` inside the loop. An example would be good to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
(cd /path && grep -vFe 'string' -- /dev/null *.filetype) > result.filetype
```

Adding `/dev/null` makes sure the matching lines are prefixed with the file path even if there's only one `*.filetype` file. With the GNU implementation of `grep`, you can also use the `-H` option for that.

The `result.filetype` will be created in the current working directory, while the other files are looked up in `/path`. As `result.filetype` matches the `*.filetype` pattern, you'll want to make sure that is not run from within `/path` or you could be running into some infinite loop end up filling up the disk.

To look for `*.filetype` files recursively, you can use `find`:

```
(
  cd /path &&
    LC_ALL=C find . -name '*.filetype' -type f -exec \
      grep -vFe 'string' -- /dev/null {} +
) > result.filetype
```

Or with the GNU implementation of `grep`:

```
(
  cd /path &&
    LC_ALL=C grep -r --include='*.filetype' -vFe 'string' .
) > result.filetype
```

(note that it will also consider hidden files).

OR with `zsh`:

```
(cd /path && grep -vFe 'string' -- /dev/null **/*.filetype(.)) > result.filetype
```

Comment: thank you, this answer is informative and approaches it in different ways. appreciate the help.

Answer (score -1):

This should help:

```
for f in *
do
  grep -v [string] "$f" > "new_$f"
done
```

Comment: Did you try this? There is nothing in the loop reading the output of `ls`.

Comment: doing `ls *.filetype` is pretty much always unnecessary, you could do just `printf "%s\n" *.filetype` instead, since it's the shell that expands the glob and `ls` will just display the filenames it's been given. Also as Kusalananda says, there's nothing in your loop reading from the stdin, i.e. that process substitution. The loop loops over the list created from that `*` glob at the top. You should probably quote `$f` too for exactly the same reasons as you quote `new_$f`.

Comment: It would suck if `foo` and `new_foo` were existing files in your directory :-). That would happen if you ran your script twice without cleaning up generated files in between, for example.